# Woocommerce: Display only option label (and not price) in mini-cart and on cart and checkout pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Form Product add-ons with Woocommerce. I have option fields where I include the option name and price as the label (so the price is clearly visible to the customer). This means, however, that the mini-cart, cart and checkout pages show the label as well as the the price and creates a bit of clutter. The images I've linked to below should show what I mean:

http://tinypic.com/r/15q5ks3/9

http://tinypic.com/r/ege6hs/9

I want to remove the price and parenthesis.

Can anyone help? :)

Darren

Comment: Could you post link ?

Comment: Hi batz, sure! The site is still in development and normally password protected. I've disabled this for a short time though. The relevant page/product is: http://connova.flywheelsites.com/produkt/abonnemang-for-privathushall/. It is in Swedish though. Just select a date in the second field, a hybridbox and then one of the options under "Frakt". You'll then be able to add to cart.

Comment: I took a llok. Which part you trying to hide? COuld add a link to screenshot with arrow on the part you want to hide?

Comment: I've highlighted the instances where this appears in the two screenshots below: 

http://tinypic.com/r/axlis/9

http://tinypic.com/r/es2nt5/9

It's the price in brackets i.e. "(249 Kr)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your template code. But in quick JS script you could solve this in front end.
Add this JS to your product page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery( ".mini_cart_item" ).each(function( index ) {
    html = jQuery(this).html();
    html = html.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
    jQuery(this).html(html);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help batz! Tweaked the code (below) and placed it in the template - it works a treat!

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery( ".variation dd li, .variation dd p" ).each(function( index ) {
    html = jQuery(this).html();
 var splitit = html.split("(");
    html = splitit[0];
    jQuery(this).html(html);
  });
})
</script>